# When Google Chrome available For Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, google

When Google Chrome available For Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile. Please we request make it available for Windows Phone all versions. We need all Google apps can run on Windows Phone 8, Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile.[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because feature requests for Windows Phone belong on https://windowsphone.uservoice.com

Answer (score 3):

I do not work for Google but I do not see Google launching the Chrome browser on Windows Phone anytime soon (or ever).

If you do want to request, request it on Google Chrome forums where Google has much better chance of seeing your request.